# GeoRSS in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, georss

I have used GeoRSS files successfully in openlayers v2.x but I am not able to find how to handle these GeoRSS files in Openlayers v3.x.

Please help if anybody has successfully tested the usage of GeoRSS in Openlayers version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the above question asked by me in 2016 was found in the extension of Openlayers given at the [link](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.source.georss.html).

We need to include ol-ext.js and ol-ext.css along with the openlayers library and jQuery.